# Canvas Image trouble

Tags: javascript, firefox, html, canvas

I am having issues with JavaScript and Canvas particularly in Firefox. I am trying to create an canvas image viewer that will run when canvas is enabled in a browser in place of standard img tag.  Javascript changes the image from an array of src paths when an arrow is clicked. For some reason Firefox is always one img out of sync.  When I test it in chrome the imgs are in sync but the first one is not displayed.

here is the image object

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = myImage.src[0];
```

here is my initial canvas intialization

```
if(canvas()){ //canvas stuff
var myc = document.createElement('canvas');
myc.id='mycanvasx';
mycanvas = document.getElementById('mycanvasx');
myc.width = image.width;
myc.height = image.height;
//viewer.replaceChild(myc, scroller);
viewer.appendChild(myc);
var context = myc.getContext("2d");
dw = image.width;
dh = image.height;

context.clearRect(0, 0, myc.width, myc.height);
context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, dw, dh); 

}
```

and when the arrow is pressed a function like this is called

```
function update(){ 
if(canvas()){
context.clearRect(0,0,myc.width, myc.height) //maybe bloat
myc.width = image.width;
myc.height = image.height;
dw = image.width;
dh = image.height;

context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, dw, dh); 

} 
} 

function left(){ //these move the image through the source array
if(myImage.num > 0){myImage.num--;}else{
myImage.num = (myImage.src.length-1)}
image.src = myImage.src[myImage.num];
scroller.src = image.src;
update();

x=0;
}
```

I know I must be missing something simple here. I'm using firefox 4.0.1 and chrome 11

Comment: It's pretty hard to tell from this code whether your issue has to do with the canvas at all, or with the `myImage` object, whose code we can't see. I'm guessing that the problem doesn't involve the canvas at all. Have you tried logging `myImage.num` and `myImage.src[myImage.num]` to a console?

Comment: the myImage object is just an array with image paths in it right now. I have tried logging the myImage.num and the log shows the correct number but canvas in Firefox does not. if I call the update() function in the console it will change to the correct image and update() does not call the myImage.num variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting the src of the image and then immediately painting it into the canvas.  But image loads are async.  So you're painting it before the new src you set has loaded; since you keep reusing the same image it's still showing the previous image at that point.

You want to run `update()` off an onload listener on `image`.